# Add the names of levels in one variable to names of levels in another variable

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Is there an easy way to add the names of levels in one variable to names of levels in another variable?

To illustrate, consider the following dataframe:

```
DF1  <- data.frame(Gender = factor(c("Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male")),
                   Wealth=factor(c("Rich", "Poor", "Rich", "Poor", "Rich", "Poor")),
                   Education=factor(c("College", "College", "HS", "College", "HS", "HS")))
```

I would like to add the genders from the `Gender` variable to the names of levels in the other two variables, like so:

```
DF2 <- data.frame(Gender = factor(c("Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male")),
                 Wealth=factor(c("MALE: Rich", "FEMALE: Poor", "FEMALE: Rich", "FEMALE: Poor", "MALE: Rich", "MALE: Poor")),
                 Education=factor(c("MALE: College", "FEMALE: College", "FEMALE: HS", "FEMALE: College", "MALE: HS", "MALE: HS")))
```

How can it be done?

Comment: Take a look at CRAN package [forcats](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forcats/index.html). It's meant to deal with factors.

Comment: How about `DF1[,-1] <- lapply(DF1[-1], function(x) paste0(DF1$Gender, ": ", x))`. Hard to say how exactly you would want to generalize that. Though this does update the `DF1` dataframe itself

Comment: Wouldn't that make of the first column redundant?

Comment: Thank you. @MrFlick: yes, combined with `toupper` to capitalize the genders your solution works.

Comment: @RuiBarradas: It does (as intended--in my actual data it's part of larger transformation that involves getting rid of the equivalent to `Gender`).

Comment: @MrFlick: by the way, is there a way to specify the columns to which the command applies, e.g. where there are more variables in the dataframe but only `Wealth` and `Education` are to be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `tidyverse` approach that makes it easy to specify a function to be applied to a selection of columns. Note that in many cases factors are amenable to string manipulations. Here we change the case with `str_to_upper`, concatenate the columns with `str_c`, and convert back to factor.

```r
DF1 <- data.frame(
  Gender = factor(c("Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male")),
  Wealth = factor(c("Rich", "Poor", "Rich", "Poor", "Rich", "Poor")),
  Education = factor(c("College", "College", "HS", "College", "HS", "HS"))
)

library(tidyverse)
DF2 <- DF1 %>%
  mutate_at(
    vars(Wealth, Education),
    funs(factor(str_c(str_to_upper(Gender), ": ", .)))
    )
DF2 %>% as_tibble()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   Gender Wealth       Education      
#>   <fct>  <fct>        <fct>          
#> 1 Male   MALE: Rich   MALE: College  
#> 2 Female FEMALE: Poor FEMALE: College
#> 3 Female FEMALE: Rich FEMALE: HS     
#> 4 Female FEMALE: Poor FEMALE: College
#> 5 Male   MALE: Rich   MALE: HS       
#> 6 Male   MALE: Poor   MALE: HS
```

Created on 2018-06-20 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).